# What happens if a batch script crashes inside a Jenkins pipeline build?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, smoke-testing

I set up Jenkins and I now want to start some serious testing. We are developing a C program so we cannot handle every possible exception. What we want to do is to make some smoke test. We want to run our program with some artificial data that accesses every part of the program to test for access violations, etc.

I wonder now, what will happen if the job does cause the program to crash?
 Can I catch that, or does it hang? What will happen? How can I handle these exceptions inside a pipeline?

Comment: The questions don't seem to have anything to do with the C language.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you are asking? What are you trying to do and what have you tried?